# SQL: shopping cart design for a multi vendor marketplace

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I'm working on a B2B marketplace where users can order from different suppliers/vendors. The following image is a sample from my original schema to clarify the cart functionality.

The `cart_item` table will hold the products that their `product.supplier_id` matches the `cart.supplier_id` because the user will have specific cart for a supplier. Is the `cart` table needed here? Or should I get rid of the `cart` table and connect `cart_item` to the `user` table directly?

Sample image[image]

Comment: Please don't [cross post to multiple sites](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66090808/3404097). Moreover this was closed as a duplicate there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modeling, it is important to understand why a particular design is chosen beyond doing what has been done before.

So going from what you have shown alone, suppliers can figure out which of their products are in carts so do not need to be linked directly to carts. From the same data, without a supplier, there’s no need to have a cart table because there isn’t discerning reason for it to exist. So really all you should have in the model are products with a foreign key to its suppliers and cart items with foreign keys to products and users.

Starting from this level, you can now determine what you need/don’t need.
If you have changing user-related information like shipping information which would have to be entered for every cart item, that’s a good reason to introduce a summary in the form of a cart entity and the user_id foreign key in cart items moves to cart (as you have it).

If there is a breakdown of a supplier (say a franchise in a particular address or sales tax based on location) which would need to be entered (chosen) for every cart item, then that makes a case for including a foreign key in cart items which eventually moves to cart to prevent duplication. If there is no breakdown of supplier or any new information that needs to be entered tied to the supplier in a cart, supplier does not need to be referenced in carts/cart items because products already know their suppliers.

As for foreign keys, unique keys and primary keys, for performance reasons in a physical model, the pattern is:

PrimaryKey: Auto-incremented value in the naming pattern <entity name(singular)>_ID e.g. cartitem_id or CartItemID.

UniqueKey: Add a unique constraint on unique key e.g. on (product_id, user_id) in cart items or on supplier name in suppliers. In associative tables, these are usually on combinations of foreign keys.

Foreign Keys: These are references to auto-incremented values in their source tables and so are the same data type and name as the values they reference.

Answer (score 0):

you need the supplier id in the card, if there are multiple suppliers for one product and the customer selects a specific supplier. but you also save ot in the card_item.

a card table you only needed, if there are multiple cards per user.
Usually you have only one card per customer, which you **can** save in such a table for later use. so i can't see ,why you want a cart per supplier. if you want to keep that transparent for the user, you will have to program a lot of logic.

You can take a look at alibaba which ia a b2b system.

the basics of every shopping system keep it simple and stupid, so that very one can use it.

Comment: Thank you @nbk! That's really helpful!